# Send TTL signal through serial port in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am trying to send a TTL signal through a serial port using Matlab. I just need to send 1 value to the device so it should be a really simple procedure. My problem is that I don't know if I am not doing this correctly or if the device is not processing the signal. My code is this:

```
mysignal = serial('com1');
fopen(mysignal);
fwrite(mysignal,1);
```

Comment: Looks okay. However, I'm not sure if `serial` is case sensitive, you'd better write 'COM1' in uppercase. I'd also recommend to use a serial terminal (such as HyperTerminal) first to make sure that the device is device at the other end is responding correctly.

Comment: @EitanT, thanks, serial is actually not case sensitive, as I can read signals from the port. I will look into the HyperTerminal as you said, since it must be the device that is not responding! Thanks for the help

Comment: I recommend using X-CTU for debugging serial devices.  It has some really useful features.  Do a google search for it; there should be a download from Digi's website.

Comment: *"send TTL signal"* -- Don't you mean a "binary value"?  I interpret "TTL signal" as referring to voltages rather than logic levels.

Comment: @sawdust, I wanted to write TTL signal here to make sure everyone understood what it is. Yes I want to send a binary value but it is TTL, so +- 5V I think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can output TTL using the actual serial port, as that is RS-232, not TTL logic levels. If you're using the serial port, you'll need a converter, like [this](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf). If you're using an FTDI driver/USB cable, that already outputs TTL logic levels, and the code looks good to me, which means the bug is probably on the device end.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I guess the problem is in the device, so I will not be able to send the signals anyways. But thanks!